# Number of Percentage in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, percentage

I have a coupon model and i am trying to calculate how much you save from the original deal.

**Coupons.rb**

```
def original_deal
  original_price
end

def our_deal
  deal_price
end

def percentage_off
  original_deal / our_deal * 100.ceil
end
```

**Show.html**

```
<%= number_to_percentage(@coupon.percentage_off, :precision => 2) %>
```

**Coupon Info**

```
original_price = £100.00
deal_price = £90.00
```

**Results.**

I get 111.11% as the answer. What am i missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your discount percentage calculation is off. You need to find the difference between the original price and the new price. And divide it by the original price to get the discount percentage:

```
def percentage_off
   (Float(original_deal - our_deal) / original_deal * 100).ceil
end
```

Your input example would now return `(100 - 90) / 100 * 100 = 10`

Comment: yea... I was wondering about that too. I'll change my answer as this is much clearer (and correct for sure)

Comment: ??? I think you have to do this: ((100-90)/­100.0*100)­.ceil (you can try it here:http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0) YOu also have to make sure the variables are floats not integer - see the added ".0" in my little example (otherwise result will be "0" instead of "10") :-)

Comment: You are right! Assuming `original_deal` and `our_deal` are not floats. I added an explicit cast to my answer, thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative, step-by-step calculation :)

```
original = 100.0
our = 90.0

our_relative = our / original # => 0.9
you_save = (1.0 - our_relative).round(2) # => 0.1
you_save_percents = (you_save * 100).round # => 10
```

Comment: As you already round to 2 decimals, the second call to `round` is not necessary anymore (although not giving problems as well).

Comment: @Veger: yeah, just being safe :)

Answer (score 1):

The calculation is coming out correct. If you look at the values you provided and do the math you come up with the following equation:

```
100.00 / 90.00 = 1.11
then you do
1.11 * 100 = 111.11
```

If you want to calculate your savings percentage, try this:

```
(original_price - deal_price) / original_price * 100.ceil
```

Hopefully that helps you out.